# How to determine the number of right bit-shifts needed for a power of two value?

Tags: c#, math, bit-manipulation

I have a function that receives a power of two value.

I need to convert it to an enum range (0, 1, 2, 3, and so on), and then shift it back to the power of two range.

```
 0         1
 1         2
 2         4
 3         8
 4        16
 5        32
 6        64
 7       128
 8       256
 9       512
10      1024
... and so on.
```

If my function receives a value of 1024, I need to convert it to 10.  What is the best way to do this in C#?  Should I just keep dividing by 2 in a loop and count the iterations?

I know I can put it back with (1 << 10).

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post the code and explain where you are stuck?

Comment: Dividing by 2 in a loop does work. It's usually not the fastest solution (it can be, for example if the input is always 0 and the branch is thus perfectly predicted "not taken") but it will reliably give the correct result. Taking a floating point log is ridiculously slow, but also works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the logarithm of base 2:

```
Math.Log(/* your number */, 2)
```

For example, `Math.Log(1024, 2)` returns 10.

Update:

Here's a rather robust version that checks if the number passed in is a power of two:

```
public static int Log2(uint number)
{
  var isPowerOfTwo = number > 0 && (number & (number - 1)) == 0;
  if (!isPowerOfTwo)
  {
    throw new ArgumentException("Not a power of two", "number");
  }

  return (int)Math.Log(number, 2);
}
```

The check for `number` being a power of two is taken from http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2

There are more tricks to find log2 of an integer on that page, starting here: 
http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogObvious

Comment: That's exactly what I need!  Thanks!  StackOverflow will not allow me to accept this as the answer for another 8 minutes, but I will.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a nice helper function for your task.

Answer (score 2):

This is the probably fastest algorithm when your CPU doesn't have a bit scan instruction or you can't access that instruction:

```
unsigned int v;  // find the number of trailing zeros in 32-bit v 
int r;           // result goes here
static const int MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[32] = 
{
  0, 1, 28, 2, 29, 14, 24, 3, 30, 22, 20, 15, 25, 17, 4, 8, 
  31, 27, 13, 23, 21, 19, 16, 7, 26, 12, 18, 6, 11, 5, 10, 9
};
r = MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[((uint32_t)((v & -v) * 0x077CB531U)) >> 27];
```

See [this paper](http://supertech.csail.mit.edu/papers/debruijn.pdf) if you want to know how it works, basically, it's just a perfect hash.

Comment: Your code is not C#. For example, `unsigned int` is not C# - in C# you would use `uint`.

Comment: As the answer says, "This is probably the fastest **algorithm** when your ...".

Answer (score 0):

Use [_BitScanForward](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/wfd9z0bb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). It does exactly this.